# Wordpress Media library accessing image captions using wp.media

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, backbone.js

I'm trying to customise the default functionality of the Wordpress media uploader. All I want to do is access the caption meta data for each image and overlay it on the thumbnail.

I've looked through the output and cant see where the image metadata is saved so i'm assuming it's AJAXed in on selection.

I've read a few articles about creating custom modals using `wp.media()` which i have got to work  but i specifically need to hook into the default modal and then loop through each image, access meta data and then append this to the thumbnail.

Just a pointer on how to access the metadata when first opening the modal would be very helpful

### EDIT+++

If i use the following code, when i select an image i can access all of the data i require

```
_media.on('select', function() {
    var attachment = _media.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    console.log(attachment);
});
```

I need the same output but from within  `_media.on('open'...)` so i can loop through all images and access their metadata from within the modal

### EDIT 2+++

So when the modal is opened, an AJAX request is sent which returns a JSON array of the meta data for the currently loaded images. The order isn't the same as the image order in the modal but this is promising. When you scroll, another request is sent andmore images are loaded, with metadata in another JSON array

Comment: You can see the `attachment` is `Object`. So, Try  `console.log( JSON.stringify(attachment));`. And then access captions like `attachment.caption`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` before for something similar from what I recall.

This will allow you to access the caption for your images which seems to be what you are looking for (I hope).  You can find out more about it [here in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `attachment.caption`, for example if you want to grab the caption and put it as the value of a field:

```
_media.on('select', function() {
  var attachment = _media.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
  console.log(attachment);
  $('#field').val(attachment.caption);
});
```

You may see [this](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2013/02/06/using-the-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/) webmaster-source.com article for further reference.

Comment: The above only works on a custom modal window, the aim is to hook into the default WP media modal. This also only shows caption for the currently selected image.